# How to shift a tensor using api in tensorflow, just like nump.roll() or shift ?

Tags: tensorflow

e.g.

For shift: from `[1, 2, 3]` to `[0, 1, 2]` or `[2, 3, 0]`

For roll:  from `[1, 2, 3]` to `[2, 3, 1]` or `[3, 1, 2]`

Thanks!